# How to make flex alignment of elements based on the previous flex item

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, css-selectors

I want to have 'text1' under the number 1 (like the 't' character should be under the 1), and 'text2' under the number 5 (like the '2' character should be under the number 5)

**It should be done dynamically, adapting to a different count of numbers**. I mean displaying under the first and last corresponding number. I'm using angular and I have the info regarding the count of the numbers in the component. **The gap between the numbers is fixed and does not change. In case of too large text then some max width can be set with wrapping to the new line.**

I have added an example of how it should work but it should be adapted to the different array of numbers

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 300px;
    }

    .container .numbers {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; 
      gap: 10px;
    }

    .container .numbers span {
      width: 30px;
      border: solid;
    }

    .container .text {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 144px;
    }
    
    span {
      border: solid;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='numbers'>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
  <div class='text'>
    <span>text1</span>
    <span>text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"How ho make flex alignment of elements based on the previous flex item"_ - not at all. There is no relationship between those elements in two completely separate flex containers, that would make this possible. Go look into `grid` instead.

Comment: @CBroe can you provide the answer using grid?

Comment: Also not possible with CSS-Grid unless specifying the number and width of columns the same for both containing divs.

Comment: I'm using angular and I have the info regarding the count of the numbers in the component

Comment: we need to know the dynamic part. The specific case you are describing can be done alone but how it should be dynamic?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Look into space-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are making something like rating....

Just change `justify-content: center;` in **.container .text** and **.container .number** class to `justify-content: space-between;`. If the numbers increased then the **text1** and **text2** will still be justified. You can play around with the widths as well.